# I am looking for a word used to describe a dresser

Tags: single-word-requests

It is a word used to describe something you sit your keys on. It's an old English word.

Comment: Well, there's always "chest of drawers", but that's typically taller than a dresser.

Comment: @NigelJ - When you come into the house and change into your casual clothes you first deposit your keys and billfold on the dresser.

Comment: Are you looking for another word for dresser? Or are you looking for more adjectives to describe the dresser?

Comment: Y’all are so organized! I leave my billfold in my pants and the keys hanging in the lock inside. Otherwise, the apartments eats them.

Comment: Console? Credenza?

Comment: @NigelJ - You change clothes by the front door?

Comment: @NigelJ - Just because you do it that way doesn't mean everyone does.

Answer (score 1):

A [*dresser*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dresser#etymonline_v_15904) as a piece of bedroom furniture only dates to 1895, a time when furniture began to be mass produced and often sold in sets or suits in a matching material and style. Earlier names for similar pieces are:

**[Commode](https://www.etymonline.com/word/commode#etymonline_v_17235)**, 1786, from French ‘convenient, suitable.’ Its days were numbered, however, when the same word was used to denote a chair with a chamber pot beneath (1851) and later, a toilet. German, whose name for the sanitary device derives from English *water closet*, had no need to switch out the same French loanword: you can buy a [*Kommode*](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/cat/kommoden-10451/) at any IKEA in Germany.

**[Bureau](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bureau#etymonline_v_18098)** as a chest of drawers dates from 1770. A bureau, for those who still use the term, is usually higher and more massive than a dresser, but still low enough to plop your keys on.

**[Chest of drawers](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chest#etymonline_v_11234)**, from the 1670s, may be of any height, which has to be specified. A dresser is essentially a low chest of drawers. Otherwise you’d have to fetch your keys with a fishing rod.